# recording audio in raw or pcm format using python

Tags: python, audio, pcm, raw

I am trying to use **porcupine** on my Jetson Nano as a wake word.
In order to do this I need to **record audio** in **pcm** format(which I believe is raw format) using **python**.
I also need the **sample rate to be 16,000** and **16bit linearly encoded on single channel**. My input device index is 11.
So, How would I be able to record audio in this format using python?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a demo already setup for this from porcupine's side.

[Checkout their demo here](https://github.com/Picovoice/porcupine/tree/master/demo/python) - it's a lot of code so I won't paste it all.

Essentially it requires installing the pvporcupinedemo package:

`$ sudo pip3 install pvporcupinedemo`

And then running the demo script ([located in the Python demo](https://github.com/Picovoice/porcupine/tree/master/demo/python)) to start running the processing:

`$ porcupine_demo_mic --access_key ${ACCESS_KEY} --keywords picovoice`

There are various arguments to this script, which can be found documented in [the repo itself](https://github.com/Picovoice/porcupine/tree/master/demo/python).

The demo explicitly states that this should work for the Jetson Nano:

> Runs on Linux (x86_64), Mac (x86_64 and arm64), Windows (x86_64),
> Raspberry Pi (all variants), NVIDIA Jetson (Nano), and BeagleBone.

To make sure the demo detects your microphone, you can run the detect mic script flag:

`$ porcupine_demo_mic --show_audio_devices`

And you should see something like:

```
index: 0, device name: USB Audio Device
index: 1, device name: MacBook Air Microphone
```

Then you can determine which mic is correct, and use the index as an argument to the demo, e.g. for the "USB Audio Device":

`$ porcupine_demo_mic --access_key ${ACCESS_KEY} --keywords picovoice --audio_device_index 0`

I would then go ahead and start picking apart the code in their [demo](https://github.com/Picovoice/porcupine/tree/master/demo/python) to modify it as required.

Comment: hello, thanks for your help but what I'm actually trying to do is pvporcupine not pvporcupinedemo so I am implementing this on python on Jetson Nano. So I just need to implement **get_next_audio_frame()** but I am currently constantly getting afailure becuase of it needs to have certain sample_rate and the audio file needs to be in pcm format. Do you know how I can implment get_next_audio_frame in this format?